# Is Changing local IP address similar to changing Public address?

Tags: networking

when accessing a website, you are asked to wait 10 minutes for example in order to make another request, suppose you are using a router as a mean to access internet (192.168.xxx.xxx), with "renewing" just the local ip address would the 10 minutes be skipped or the address given to the router is the one that should be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the host uses the IP to identify you:

The host you are connecting to sees the public address, and this is what then needs to be renewed. You can try it yourself; grab another device on the same network as the one you used first, and try to connect. You'll find that you still have to wait. The local IP-address can only identify you within the local network.

The reason is that there's a limited number of IPv4 adresses, so only your router get's a public IP-address, and then your devices get's a local IP from the router. The router then works to send the packages directed at the public address to the correct local IP.

Answer (score 1):

If you renew your local pc ip address this only affects your local home network. Any requests to the Internet will see the ip address given to you by your isp (the one on your router).